# How can I modify a cabal package installed onto my computer

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm trying to use wxHaskell to modify wxAsteroids. Every time I try to change something within the wxAsteroids1.1.0.1.tar.gz folder it does not affect the program. Is there a way to update the wxAsteroids.exe in order to use the code? Unzipping the .tar.gz gives me this error when trying to run Asteroids.lhs:

`could not find module 'Paths_wxAsteroids'
 Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.`

Answer (score 1):

```
tar xzf wxAstroids*
```

This will get your the package in a `wxAstroids-<version>` directory.  Change to that directory and...

```
vi xAstroids.cabal
-- Edit the file, add Paths_wxAstroids to the other-modules: list.
```

Now the package should be fixed, so reinstall this fixed version

```
cabal install
```

Yay!